# Exception: Do not call this method if VisualChildrenCount returns zero. When trying to change the Visibility of the User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, user-controls, code-behind

I added a customized user control to a Window in WPF (C#).
When I try to change the visibility of the control in code-behind, application throws the exception

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
>   Specified index is out of range or child at index is null. *Do not call this method if VisualChildrenCount returns zero*, indicating that the Visual has no children.

Edit: Relevant Code (Snippet out of the large code)

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestClient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:trend="clr-namespace:MultiseriesChartControl;assembly=MultipleLinesView"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <trend:MultipleLinesView x:Name="multipleLinesView"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MultipleLinesViewModel vModel = new MultipleLinesViewModel();
        Color sColor = Colors.Lime;
        multipleLinesView.CreateSeries("test", sColor, true);
        multipleLinesView.AttachData("test", ref vModel);

        MultipleLinesViewModel vModelTest = new MultipleLinesViewModel();
        Color tColor = Colors.MediumPurple;
        multipleLinesView.CreateSeries("test2", tColor, true);
        multipleLinesView.AttachData("test2", ref vModelTest);
    }
}
```

This is the `MainWindow`
[image]

After clicking on the close button. Exception is thrown. And when continuing, UI becomes blank.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you’re calling the `someFn` method before the control is loaded. 
Don’t change the control’s visibility before the execution `InitializeComponents()` is completed.

**EDIT :**
As mentioned above, you were trying to set the UserControl’s visibility before that component is loaded. 
The reason for this is the code that you have mentioned in `Windows_Loaded` function is executed before `InitializeComponents()`. Hence when the close button is pressed, the data is not loaded into the usercontrol and hence the ex.

**Fix**  : To fix the issue, just move the code in `Window_Loaded` to the `Constructor` after the call of `InitializeComponents()` as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: There is no problem in showing the UserControl for the first time.
I have a button that hides the UserControl.
The above-mentioned exception is thrown in
`UserControl_IsVisibleChanged` method, when trying to hide the control.

Comment: Without seeing the entire code, cannot say how the issue is being caused. Is the button within the control or outside it?

Comment: Just move the code in `Window_Loaded` to the `Constructor` after the call of `InitializeComponents()` and tell if the issue still exists. Also specify at which line the exception is caught.

Comment: Yeah.. After moving the code it works.
Can you explain what is the difference?

Comment: @SabhareeshRavichandran : If your issue is fixed, you could mark this answer as the correct answer by clicking on the green tick, so it will be helpful for others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add inside Window_Loaded

```
 if(multipleLinesView.IsLoaded){
    DoThings(...);
 }
```